# How to calculate the delta value for each sample in Time To Sample Box of Mp4 file?

Tags: iframe, time, mp4, sample, mp4parser

Here is an example of an entry in Time To Sample Box (stts) in a Mp4 file:

```
Entry{count=1, delta=4147}
```

How they calculate the value of delta. I guess it involves I or B frames. But I didn't find any instruction. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you figured it out meanwhile, please let me know! I am dealing with the exact same problem right now: How to compute the delta(s)..

Comment: @gilgamash Unfortunately there is no method for calculating the value of delta.

Answer (score 0):

In `mdhd` there is `Time Scale` atom that is the number of time units that pass per second. You can use it to calculate times.

Comment: sample_delta = mdcd_timeScale / FPS. Is it correct?